# Sidebar sometimes above and sometimes below content in responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a website where sometimes the content in the sidebar is the most important of the website, so on those pages, the sidebar has to be placed above the other content in a responsive design.
On other pages, the sidebar has to be placed below the other content.

It's quite easy to solve this by switching the order of the divs in the html, but I think this isn't a clean solution. I think it might look weird for search engines to see a complete different order of the divs on different pages.
Here's what I mean:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle links: http://jsfiddle.net/YEUwN/107/ and http://jsfiddle.net/YEUwN/108/

So I'm looking for a different solution where the html is the same for both orderings. Is this possible with css for example?

Comment: A sidebar normally doesn't contain super important content. Maybe it's an idea to hide a div on desktop, with the same content as sidebar and display it when on mobile?

Comment: Two times the same content in the html is definitely something that should be avoided with SEO in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS3 using [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/). [Read more here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YEUwN/109/)**

You can change the flex order as you like.

CSS

```
 #container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#sidebar {
 width: 100%;
 order: 1;
}

#content {
 width: 100%;
 order: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It does work, however I'm a little afraid about the supported browsers. If anyone has a similar (more supported) solution, share please! :)

Comment: @OsiriX See this http://caniuse.com/flexbox You can use -webkit / -moz prefix to get more support

Comment: Yeah I know, I was checking my analytics to see what browsers my visitors are using. Flexbox will support almost all of them so I'll go with this solution! Thank you.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about this anymore. I've edited it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YEUwN/118/
However, I notice I still can't get it working in the Android 4.0 browser for example or Firefox 27. Is the above solution not possible with "partial support"?